# Do not want to allow Queries to take more than x minutes?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

Do not want to allow Queries to take more than x minutes ! What System variable can I set to automatically terminate it.

Comment: Have you seen these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794747/mysql-can-i-limit-the-maximum-time-allowed-for-a-query-to-run and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 5.7 ; you can use [max_execution_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time)

From the documentation:

> **Statement Execution Time Optimizer Hints**
>
> The `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` hint is permitted only for `SELECT` statements. It places a limit N (a timeout value in milliseconds) on how long a statement is permitted to execute before the server terminates it:
>
> ```
> MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N)
> ```
>
> Example with a timeout of 1 second (1000 milliseconds):
>
> ```
> SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE ...
> ```
>
> The `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N)` hint sets a statement execution timeout of N milliseconds. If this option is absent or N is 0, the statement timeout established by the max_execution_time system variable applies.
>
> The `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` hint is applicable as follows:
>
> - For statements with multiple `SELECT` keywords, such as unions or statements with subqueries, `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` applies to the entire statement and must appear after the first `SELECT`.
> - It applies to read-only `SELECT` statements. Statements that are not read only are those that invoke a stored function that modifies data as a side effect.
> - It does not apply to `SELECT` statements in stored programs and is ignored.